# How the Correlation Matrix is built for PCA in Weka?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, weka, correlation-matrix

Just to give a context, I want to use PCA (Principal Component Analysis) to identify which attributes are similar to others, so I can use just one (or a subset) of them.
The correlation matrix of n variables X1, ..., Xn is the n×n matrix whose i,j entry is corr(Xi, Xj).

So if I have 8 attributes, I would have a correlation matrix of size of 8x8.
After running PCA in Weka for 8 attributes, the output shows me a Correlation matrix of size of 44x44. And printed 26 Selected attributes.

**My question:** Shouldn't my correlation matrix have the size of 8x8? How does weka build such matrix?

Thanks!!

MC

Comment: If you have 8 features then your correlation matrix should be 8x8. The question about Weka is off-topic though.

Comment: Do you have 44 observations on your 8 variables?

Comment: @user116100, do you have 44 observations on your 8 variables?

Comment: @Firebug, I believed my question is about PCA and not Weka, but I mentioned Weka just to give more details what I am doing. :)

Comment: @gung, I have 5725 instances. Do you what these 44 columns/rows does represent if there are not my 8 attributes?

Comment: Are the 8 attributes categorical variables? If so, do they have >2 levels? How many levels would there be in total across the 8 attributes?

Comment: @gung: My attributes are nominal and have > 2 different values (I believed you called them as 'levels'). Thanks!

Comment: I believe I found **an explanation for the 44 attr**: when I set transformBackToOriginal=true in Weka, I get 44 attr (I'll call them "intermediate attr". They came from my original attr and I believe they're used to created the new PCA attr. Ex: my original attr are _food[rice, beans, pasta, lettuce]_; my intermediate attr would be _food=rice_ and food=pasta_. And then weka use these intermediate attributes do create the final attributes of PCA. But not sure how and why weka choose _food=rice_ and food=pasta_ and does not choose _food=beans_ and food=lettuce_. Probably based on their variance?

Comment: Sorry there isn't a good answer here yet, I have the same question.  I'm using the iris dataset, with 4 features and a target/class, and I get back a 7x7 correlation matrix.  My guess is that because there are **3 categories** in the target (setosa, virginica and versicolor), that accounts for the additional unexpected rows/cols in my correlation matrix.  **4 features + 3 classes = 7 rows** (and columns).  I'd love feedback if this is maybe on the right track.

Comment: @Bigo - maybe you can let us know here if you had categorical information, and if so, how many categories in total?

Answer (score 1):

In Weka, if you don't set the target class, it may treat each categorical value as another potential component.

Example:  Iris Data

If you take the Iris data set, by default the class is not set, and the Attribute Selection Model shows "No Class".  There are 4 features (sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width) and three class categories (setosa, versicolor, virginica).  Running PCA with the default setting  returns a 7x7 correlation matrix.

```
Correlation matrix
  1     -0.11   0.87   0.82  -0.72   0.08   0.64 
 -0.11   1     -0.42  -0.36   0.6   -0.46  -0.13 
  0.87  -0.42   1      0.96  -0.92   0.2    0.72 
  0.82  -0.36   0.96   1     -0.89   0.12   0.77 
 -0.72   0.6   -0.92  -0.89   1     -0.5   -0.5  
  0.08  -0.46   0.2    0.12  -0.5    1     -0.5  
  0.64  -0.13   0.72   0.77  -0.5   -0.5    1
```

And you can see the top eigenvector returns components including the classes, which is probably not desirable:

```
eigenvalue  proportion  cumulative
  4.34646     0.62092     0.62092   0.476petallength+0.465petalwidth-0.451class=Iris-setosa+0.411sepallength+0.349class=Iris-virginica...
  1.76093     0.25156     0.87248   0.7  class=Iris-versicolor-0.471class=Iris-virginica-0.451sepalwidth-0.229class=Iris-setosa-0.158sepallength...
  0.68223     0.09746     0.96995   -0.75sepalwidth-0.441sepallength-0.36class=Iris-versicolor+0.325class=Iris-virginica-0.073petallength...
```

**Setting the Attribute Selection drop down to "(Nom) Class"** removes the target categories from the Correlation Matrix and eigenvectors, and will return a 4x4 Correlation matrix.

```
Correlation matrix
  1     -0.11   0.87   0.82 
 -0.11   1     -0.42  -0.36 
  0.87  -0.42   1      0.96 
  0.82  -0.36   0.96   1
```

```
eigenvalue  proportion  cumulative
  2.91082     0.7277      0.7277    -0.581petallength-0.566petalwidth-0.522sepallength+0.263sepalwidth
  0.92122     0.23031     0.95801   0.926sepalwidth+0.372sepallength+0.065petalwidth+0.021petallength
```

[image: set the dropdown to (Nom) class]